# How Can I Remove All Characters After a Certain Character Appears Twice Using Bash Scripting?

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch-rename

I have multiple files in a directory *over 200* which I would like to rename by removing all other characters including the character and the rest after it appears twice.

Example:

One of the files in the directory is

```
Akouo - Float-H6hQuio26Ww.mp3
```

I would like a bash script which removes the second hyphen and all characters after it excluding the extension.

The end result should be

```
Akouo - Float.mp3
```

Comment: only bash? no python script?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Python is welcomed. Variety is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename your example

```
Akouo - Float-H6hQuio26Ww.mp3
```

to

```
Akouo - Float.mp3
```

use

```
rename 's/-[^-]*\././' Akouo\ -\ Float-H6hQuio26Ww.mp3
```

If you want to rename all .mp3 files in your current directory with this schema, use

```
rename 's/-[^-]*\././' *-*-*.mp3
```

You can add option `-n` for a dry run.

Comment: If the file has 3+ hyphens in it, this will only remove from the last hyphen. You should consider using backreferences.

Comment: @Cyrus Wow! Thank you very much. It worked. I am not too familiar with bash. I like explanations. Can you edit your question to include an explanation of your script? It'll be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, this is beyond the scope. As an introduction to Regex I would recommend this: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html

Answer (score 1):

If we assume *all* files have two or more hypens and all files are mp3's, renaming (in python) would only take a few lines:

```py
hyps = [i for i in range(len(name)) if name[i] == "-"]
name = name[:hyps[1]]+"mp3"
```

However, in my opinion, a script should (without explicit information that it is not necessary) take at least into account the possibility that the directory has sub-directories and/or contains:

- hidden files
- files with no extension
- files with varying types of extensions
- file names have only one, more then two or no hypens

so that:

```
file1-2-3-4-5.txt
a-b-c-d-e
Akouo - Float-H6hQuio26Ww.mp3
```

becomes:

```
file1-2.txt
a-b
Akouo - Float.mp3
```

Then the script is a bit more extensive:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import shutil
import os

sourcedir = "/path/to/files"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcedir):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith(".") or name.count("-") < 2:
            pass
        else:
            if name.count(".") == 0:
                extension = ""
            else:
                extension = name[name.rfind("."):]
            hyps = [i for i in range(len(name)) if name[i] == "-"]
            newname = name[:hyps[1]].strip()+extension
            shutil.move(root+"/"+name, root+"/"+newname)
```

Copy the script into an empty file, set the path to your directory and save it as `rename.py`. Run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/rename.py
```

Comment: Awesome @Jacob. Thank you for this answer and elaboration.